# How to Display Post Content in an Accordion Using Gutenberg+ ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

I have an accordion which is inserted as a Post Object ACF. Each accordion item is a post. I have separate ACF + Gutenberg content blocks that I insert into a post. Now the problem is that when opening the accordion, it is empty and does not see the content block. How can I display Gutenberg blocks inside a post?

```js
<div class="accordion-block">
    <?php if (!empty($choose_acc_item)) : ?>
        <?php
        foreach ($choose_acc_item as $item) : ?>
            <div class="accordion-block__item">
                <button class="accordion-item__title"><?php echo $item->post_title; ?>
                </button>
                <div class="accordion-item__content">
                    <?php echo $item->post_content; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php
        endforeach;
    endif; ?>

</div>
```

In the code inspector:

[image: Output value]

There should be a video, the block of which I made with ACF + Gutenberg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the `apply_filters()` function on the content to run all of the content hooks. this should make the video display although the code is untested.

```
<div class="accordion-block">
    <?php if (!empty($choose_acc_item)) : ?>
        <?php
        foreach ($choose_acc_item as $item) : ?>
            <div class="accordion-block__item">
                <button class="accordion-item__title"><?php echo $item->post_title; ?>
                </button>
                <div class="accordion-item__content">
                    <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $item->post_content); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php
        endforeach;
    endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: this was a very helpful tip! thank you Samuel!